# Automatically Fix "missing semicolon before statement"

Tags: javascript, minify

I have a large javascript file that is missing a lot of semicolons. It works fine as it is, but when I try to use a minifier = kaboom! Is there a way to automatically fix this? I tried to go manually through it but it's not humanly possible.

Comment: You could also use a [better minifier](http://refresh-sf.com/yui/), that does insert semicolons between statements.

Answer (score 0):

check out the [JavaScript Lint](http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php) application that checks your script for common errors (semicolon, curly brackets, trailing decimals, nested comments, etc.)

Comment: I don't want to highlight them, I want to correct them automatically.